# How do I make a script start up a terminal and run a text line on bash?

Tags: bash

I am pretty sure its simple,  I just couldn't find an answer that fit bash or linux. Here is my script, its really short:

```
gnome-terminal
echo "you heff bin hackt"
$SHELL
```

I wanted to make it just as a quick joke but I am having issues with it. It opens the terminal but does not run the text line. What is going wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--command` option

```
gnome-terminal --command="/bin/echo 'msg'; $SHELL"
```

#### edit

`--command` is on deprecation path, so `--` is a better option

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "/bin/echo 'msg'; $SHELL"
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this. I figured it was something along those lines.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I cant get this to work. I am probably just ignorant of an extra line somewhere or something, your code there just opens a terminal and does nothing else, like my code did.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the text if you open any new terminal session, you could add your command to the `.bashrc` file:

```
echo 'echo "message"' >> ~/.bashrc
```